# A dice with numbers 1 to 10 is thrown 4 times. Find the probability that result has 3 consecutive prime or no prime shows up three times consecutively

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, dice

Here is the exact wording in the problem given.

Numbers from 1 to 10 are printed on a fair 10-faced dice. The dice is thrown 4 times.
Find the probability the result has 3 consecutive prime numbers or no prime number shows up 3 times consecutively.

Here's my approach so far. I am a Math Olympiad enthusiast so you can use any such math.
In a throw,
P(prime) = 4/10 = 2/5
P(not prime) 6/10 = 3/5

Next

P(3 consecutive primes) = 2 x (2/5)^3 x (3/5) = 48/625

because 2 configurations ppp_ or _ppp so we need to multiply by 2.

also

P(no primes appear 3 times consecutively)
= 1 - P (some prime number appears 3 times consecutively)
=  1 - 2 x (4/10) (1/10)^2 x (9/10)
= 1241/1250

Because 2 configurations as before (so multiply by 2)
(4/10) is probability of first prime followed by (1/10)^2 as probability of next two consecutive but "same" prime with the first while (9/10) is probability for selection of remaining throw to be any number except the repeated prime here.

I wondered if there is an overlap to the cases above by Principle of Inclusion Exclusion which we need to subtract after adding the numbers above

P(Overlap) ---> add the following breakdown of cases:

P(all three primes different)
=  2 x (4/10)(3/10)(2/10) x 10/10 - (4/10)(1/10)^3
2 configurations PPP_ or *PPP
(4/10) represents probability choice for first prime
(3/10) represents probability choice for second prime which must be different from the first
(2/10) represents probability choice for third prime which must be different from both earlier ones.
(10/10) represents that the remaining number "*" can be either a prime or a non-prime.
We minus (4/10)(1/10)^3 because that part is repeated in both configurations above as case with PPPP.

+

P(two primes only exactly the same which we count in two configuration sets as counting is not symmetrical within both)

= P(configurations P1P1P2_ or P1P2P1_ or _P2P1P1 or _P1P2P1)

- P(Configurations P2P1P1_ or _P1P1P2)

= 4 (4/10)(1/10)(3/10)(8/10) + 2 x (4/10)(1/10)(3/10)(9/10)

In calculator
P(overlap) = 243/2500

So Probability we seek is
= 48/625 + 1241/1250 - 243/2500
= 2431/2500

Problem: The answer key (no solution) given states that the answer is 253/625. How to get it please and where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow. Proper formatting would help.  Note in the first (second) case you need to handle the scenario in which all $4$ tosses are prime (composite).

Comment: Note too that the final answer you get, $\frac {2431}{2500}$ seems much too high.  You are claiming near certainty, but outcomes with, say, exactly two primes, are likely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say that the question has been very poorly posed.

By doing reverse engineering, I have concluded that what they are actually asking is the probability that in $4$ throws, you get **at least** $3$ primes or $3$ **non-primes** (i.e. by "no prime" they mean non-prime)

Leaving out the denominator (which will always be $625$)

number of favorable cases $$= 2(2^3*3) +2^4 + 2(3^3*2) +3^4 = 253$$ $\quad\quad\quad and\; Pr= \dfrac{253}{625}
$

Comment: Hi Anil, thank you so much for clarifying what the question was "trying to ask". Indeed it was some "bad English" but you did manage to figure it out! I appreciate it and I understand what you are saying here.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers ! $\;\;$ :)